# MacBook Pro freezes and shows console error messages

Tags: macbook-pro, console, kernel-panic

When I log in to my MacBook Pro (Mac OS X 10.5.8 w/ Intel 2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, and 4 GB of DDR3 ram with a few bad sectors), it started entering my desktop but returned me to the log in screen.

So, I took my MacBook Pro to the nearest Apple Store (where they were holding the memorial for Steve Jobs and I had to wait for hours) :'(, where they determined that one of my launch preferences was corrupted. They created a new account, and they transferred data from my old account to the new one without the bad preferences.

After I got back, my computer continued to work and Spotlight started its indexing again. However, the MacBook Pro started to spontaneously panic (but *not* a kernel panic) and shows console error messages over the desktop (which freezes). This happens out of the blue without provocation. Here is a screen shot from my iPhone:

[image: panic message]

Does anyone knows how to fix this??? The problem is I need to do some critical tasks on this computer for the next 7 days, and won't have access to any reinstallation media before then. So I hope I can apply at least a temporary fix for now...

Thanks!

Comment: At the Apple store did they check the hardware ? If so I'd say to do a clean install. Will save you a lot of troubleshooting time.

Comment: I think they did check the hardware and didn't find any problems. The thing is I need to use this computer for some critical tasks for the next week, and I won't have access to re-installation media before then.....

Comment: That's quite the bizarre problem, and I highly doubt you'll be able to fix it without doing a reinstall and/or getting a hardware repair. Make 1000% sure your disk is backed up, and get it to a store as soon as you can.